# how to generate a trimodal distribution (mixture) in c++ with random library?

Tags: c++11, random, normal-distribution

i'm using random c++11 library to generate random numbers. Now I want to generate a mixture of three normal distribution, with mean 50,100 and 150 and std dev 10. How can I do it?
Thank you.
GL

Comment: That is an interesting problem.  Are you asking for the general algorithm?  Or are you asking for the correct syntax to implement a known algorithm.  Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API in the std::lib which directly supports multimodal distributions.  You will have to build your trimodal distribution out of the unimodal normal distribution which *is* supplied by the standard:

```
template <class RealType = double>
class normal_distribution;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this by randomly choosing between 3 normal distributions,

like:

```
a=rand(1,3)
switch(a)
case 1:
  res=rand_from_first_normal_distribution();
case 2:
  res=rand_from_second_normal_distribution();
case 3:
  res=rand_from_third_normal_distribution();
```

Anyway, the deadline for this course has been extended to the 16th of february, so don't worry :)

Comment: This worked for me when generating random samples from a mixture distribution. It would not work when estimating the actual mixture distribution functions. However it had a down vote - please add comment if you down vote to let everyone know why you think the answer is bad.